# Swift - how to extract property type of each attribute of an NSOBJECT entity

Tags: ios, swift, date, picker

I have 2 methods which put both the attribute names and the attribute values (from a Core Data store) into separate arrays.  How can I also put the property type into yet another separate array.  these two arrays below ultimately populate a tableview and I need to be able to identify which properties are date fields so I can use the date picker.

```
func generateValueList2 (order: [String]) -> [String] {
    return order.map { (animal!.value(forKey: $0) as? String ?? "") }
}

//this is under development - need to return array of attribute types
func generateValueList2 (order: [String]) -> [String] {
    return order.map { (animal!.type(forKey: $0) as? String ?? "") }
}
```

Comment: Why? What is the benefit of doing that?

Comment: I have a page that has a table view with the prototype cell containing the property name on the left as a UILabel and the value on the right as a UITextField that the user can edit the value and then save it as the new value for that property of the object.  I use the two separate arrays to feed the content for the table view.  Some of those properties are date types, so I need to check for when the particular row contains a date type field so that I can queue the textfield to use the date picker.